# CPython - Read Python Dictionary (keys/values) inside a C Function Passed as argument

Tags: python, cpython

I am writing a Python C extension. I am passing a Python `dict` to a C function. I am able to parse it, using the following code:

```
PyObject *large_dict = NULL;
if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "O!", &PyDict_Type, &large_dict)) return NULL;
if (large_dict != NULL)
{
   printf("Large Dictionary Not Null\n");
}
```

Here the statement "Large Dictionary Not Null" is printed, which means that the dictionary is parsed successfully.
Now I want to access the dictionary values by specifying keys, like we do in Python. For example, `large_dict['k1']` would give value `v1`.

How can I access dictionary keys/values inside this C function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should go through the link, https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/dict.html
Excerpt given below,

```
PyObject* PyDict_GetItem(PyObject *p, PyObject *key)
Return value: Borrowed reference.
Return the object from dictionary p which has a key key. Return NULL if the key key is not present, but without setting an exception.

PyObject* PyDict_GetItemString(PyObject *p, const char *key)
Return value: Borrowed reference.
This is the same as PyDict_GetItem(), but key is specified as a char*, rather than a PyObject*.

PyObject* PyDict_Items(PyObject *p)
Return value: New reference.
Return a PyListObject containing all the items from the dictionary, as in the dictionary method dict.items().

PyObject* PyDict_Keys(PyObject *p)
Return value: New reference.
Return a PyListObject containing all the keys from the dictionary, as in the dictionary method dict.keys().

PyObject* PyDict_Values(PyObject *p)
Return value: New reference.
Return a PyListObject containing all the values from the dictionary p, as in the dictionary method dict.values().
```

Keep an eye on `borrowed reference / new reference`. It is little tricky while coding for Python extensions.

Comment: Something like [this](https://github.com/aerospike/aerospike-client-python/blob/master/src/main/conversions.c#L155)

Comment: Isn't Python 2 a tad old?

Answer (score 0):

I'll reply for Python 3.7+, since that's the most likely use case these days (see [reference](https://docs.python.org/3.7/c-api/dict.html)). Converting from/to C types is dependent on the Python type of the keys/values, which you haven't specified. For the sake of illustrating an actual use-case, let's assume the keys and values are both positive integers. Then if you want to retrieve the value for `k1=42` then I think you can do this:

```
   unsigned int k1 = 42;
   PyObject *py_k1 = PyLong_FromUnsignedLong(k1);
   PyObject *py_v1 = PyDict_GetItem(large_dict, py_k1);
   unsigned int v1 = PyLong_AsUnsignedLong(py_v1);
```

Breaking this down line by line, the first line defines the key as a plain C `unsigned int`. But we can't use a regular C type to index into a Python dict, therefore in the second line we define a pointer to a Python type that will point to the key. We then do the C equivalent of Python's `large_dict[k1]` via `PyDict_GetItem`, but using the pointer we created as the key and obtaining a pointer to a Python type as the value. Finally, if we want to access the value as a regular C type, we need to convert it in the last line, which is the reverse of what we did in the second line.

Note: `PyDict_GetItem` returns a borrowed reference, so we don't need to worry about reference counting.